# When main report query have multiple results sets and subreport input as parameter could not generate PDF?

Tags: java, jasper-reports, subreport, bytearrayinputstream

My JasperReports's report has subreport. Using the `ByteArrayInputStream` parameter into the main report and main report query result have more than one row Could not generate pdf. But the main report query result set has an only one result  set PDF to generate without any error

My Java code for passing subreport:

```
Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<String, Object>(); 
parameters.put("subreportParameter", subreportinputstream)
```

Declaration of parameter at *jrxml*:

```
<parameter name="subreportParameter" class="java.io.ByteArrayInputStream"/>
```

This is how I'm calling subreport:

```
 <subreport>
   <reportElement positionType="Float" x="275" y="55" width="240" height="70" uuid="0010fc8e-593e-45ee-af10-952fd8b54ad5" />
   <subreportParameter name="reportid">
      <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{reportid}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
   </subreportParameter>
   <subreportParameter name="currencycode">
      <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{currencycode}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
   </subreportParameter>
   <subreportParameter name="taxcode">
      <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{taxcode}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
   </subreportParameter>
   <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
   <subreportExpression class="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperReport"><![CDATA[$P{subreportParameter}]]></subreportExpression>
</subreport>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the subreport renders the second time, it tries to load the report from the `$P{subreportParameter}` input stream, but that stream has already been read the first time the subreport rendered so reading from it again will not produce any data.

The simplest way to fix this is to set the `isUsingCache` flag for the subreport:

```
<subreport isUsingCache="true">
    ...
```

Alternatively, you can load the `JasperReport` object yourself from the stream by doing `JRLoader.loadObject(subreportinputstream)` and pass the `JasperReport` object as report parameter instead of the stream.